# Constructing a graph and performing a depth-first traversal

Tags: c++, c++11, graph, pointers, depth-first-search

Please review the use of pointers and design in graph construction code and its depth first traversal. I haven't used smart pointers as I want to understand any issues in following implementation with raw pointers.

Graphs.h

```
namespace DS {

    struct Vertex;
    typedef std::list<Vertex*> VerticesList;
    typedef std::map<int, VerticesList::const_iterator> DataVertexMap;
    class Graph {

        VerticesList _verticesList;
        DataVertexMap _dataVertexMap;

        //TODO: Need some design to have this function internal only and not exposed to client
        Vertex* addAndGetVertex(int data);
    public:
        Graph();
        ~Graph();

        bool isEmpty();
        //We don't check for duplicate vertex
        void addVertex(int data);
        void addEdge(int srcData, int dstData, int cost);
        int getCostForEdge(int srcData, int dstData);
        void displayGraph();
        void dfsTraversal();

    };

} //End namespace DS
```

Graphs.cpp

```
#include "Graphs.h"
#include <stack>

namespace DS {

    struct Vertex;

    typedef struct Edge {
        int cost;
        struct Vertex* srcVertex;
        struct Vertex* dstVertex;
    }Edge;

    typedef std::list<Edge*> EdgeList;
    class Vertex {
    public:
        Vertex() {
            bVisited = false;
        }
        int data;
        EdgeList edgeList;
        bool bVisited;
    };

    Graph::Graph() {

    }

    Graph::~Graph() {
        for (std::list<Vertex*>::const_iterator iter = _verticesList.begin(); iter != _verticesList.end(); ++iter) {
            Vertex * vertex = *iter;
            std::list<Edge*> edgeList = vertex->edgeList;
            for (std::list<Edge*>::const_iterator edgeIter = edgeList.begin(); edgeIter != edgeList.end(); ++edgeIter) {
                delete *edgeIter;
            }

            delete vertex;
        }
    }

    bool Graph::isEmpty() {
        return _verticesList.empty();
    }

    void Graph::addVertex(int data) {
        Vertex* node = new Vertex();
        node->data = data;
        node->edgeList.clear();

        VerticesList::const_iterator iter = _verticesList.insert(_verticesList.end(), node);
        _dataVertexMap.insert(std::make_pair(data, iter));
    }

    Vertex* Graph::addAndGetVertex(int data) {
        Vertex* node = new Vertex();
        node->data = data;
        node->edgeList.clear();

        VerticesList::const_iterator iter = _verticesList.insert(_verticesList.end(), node);
        //TODO: Evaluate if this is right approach to insert in map i.e iterator
        _dataVertexMap.insert(std::make_pair(data, iter));

        return node;
    }

    void Graph::addEdge(int srcData, int dstData, int cost) {
        DataVertexMap::const_iterator srcIter = _dataVertexMap.find(srcData);
        DataVertexMap::const_iterator dstIter = _dataVertexMap.find(dstData);

        Vertex* srcVertex = NULL;
        Vertex* dstVertex = NULL;
        if(srcIter == _dataVertexMap.end())
            srcVertex = addAndGetVertex(srcData);
        else
            srcVertex = *(srcIter->second);

        if(dstIter == _dataVertexMap.end())
            dstVertex = addAndGetVertex(dstData);
        else
            dstVertex = *(dstIter->second);

        Edge* newEdge = new Edge();
        newEdge->cost = cost;
        newEdge->srcVertex = srcVertex;
        newEdge->dstVertex = dstVertex;

        srcVertex->edgeList.push_back(newEdge);

    }

    int Graph::getCostForEdge(int srcData, int dstData) {
        DataVertexMap::const_iterator srcIter = _dataVertexMap.find(srcData);
        DataVertexMap::const_iterator dstIter = _dataVertexMap.find(dstData);

        if(srcIter == _dataVertexMap.end() || dstIter == _dataVertexMap.end())
            return -1;

        EdgeList edgeList = (*(srcIter->second))->edgeList;
        for (EdgeList::const_iterator iter = edgeList.begin(); iter != edgeList.end(); ++iter) {
            Edge* edge  = *iter;
            if(edge->dstVertex == *(dstIter->second))
                return edge->cost;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    void Graph::displayGraph() {

    }

    void Graph::dfsTraversal() {
        std::stack<Vertex*> vertexStack;
        vertexStack.push(_verticesList.front());

        while(!vertexStack.empty())
        {
            Vertex *vertex = vertexStack.top();
            vertexStack.pop();
            vertex->bVisited = true;
            printf("%d\n", vertex->data);
            const EdgeList edgeList = vertex->edgeList;
            for (EdgeList::const_iterator iter = edgeList.begin(); iter != edgeList.end(); ++iter) {
                Edge *edge = *iter;
                Vertex *dstVertex = edge->dstVertex;
                if(!dstVertex->bVisited)
                    vertexStack.push(dstVertex);
            }
        }

       //TODO: mark visited back to false for each node.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I won't go into detail about memory management now, but it seems to be correct. You are deleting the edges and vertexes in the destructors, so you should't have any leaks.

**Things you could improve in the code**:

- No need to define an empty constructor. Don't provide one if you have no manual initialization to perform.
- You don't have to `typedef struct` in C++, like you would in C. Just `struct Edge { };` is enough.
- Beginning with C++11, you can now directly initialize member variables on declaration. So you could init `Vertex::bVisited` directly. E.g.: `bool bVisited = false;`. I also recommend initializing `Vertex::data` to zero or some other default value.
- The `for` loops in Graph's destructor are quite verbose and long. You could make them a lot more concise by using [range based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).
- Methods that don't mutate state of an object should be `const`. `isEmpty()` is an example: `bool isEmpty() const;` This is [Const Correctness](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html).
- Several declaration are using the long winded `iterator` and `const_iterator` names. You could simplify all of them by using [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) and letting the compiler do the type inference for you.
- Don't use `NULL` in C++. This is very outdated. Start using [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr).
- Names starting with an `_` are [arguable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/1198654). `_verticesList` and `_dataVertexMap` are not wrong though, but this practice might still be disapproved by some, as it might lead to eventually slipping such a name into the global namespace. Consider other options such as an underscore at the end, `likeThis_` or the also popular `m_` prefix, `m_likeThis`. Or no prefix/suffix at all.
- `printf` is cool, I like it `;)`. But this is C++ land, so you should give [`std::cout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) the preference. If you do use `printf` though, `#include <cstdio>` and call it using the `std::` namespace: `std::printf("Hello");`.

There are probably more aspect and points to note. Hopefully other reviewers will expand on this list.

Answer (score 7):

There is at least one place where you may have problems with raw pointers. It has to do with [exception safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety) and the piece of code I am talking about is the method `addVertex` (but it also applies to `addAndGetVertex`):

```
void Graph::addVertex(int data) {
    Vertex* node = new Vertex();
    node->data = data;
    node->edgeList.clear();

    VerticesList::const_iterator iter = _verticesList.insert(_verticesList.end(), node);
    _dataVertexMap.insert(std::make_pair(data, iter));
}
```

Here, you are allocating memory for a `Vertex`, then you try to add it at the end of `_verticesList`. When inserting an element in an `std::list`, a new node should be allocated. Unless otherwise specified, `std::list` uses [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) to allocate new memory, which is based on `new` and `delete`. In other words, if there is no more free memory to allocate for the new node, `new` will throw an [`std::bad_alloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) exception and `insert` will rethrow the exception. In `addVertex`, if `insert` throws, then the newly allocated `Vertex` (`node`) will not be freed. This is a memory leak, and so your method fails to provide the **basic exception safety** (also known as **no-leak guarantee**).

If you use a smart pointer to allocate the memory, then when `insert` throws, your method won't catch the exception, but the destructors of the [automatic variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) of the method will be called. Therefore, the destructor of the smart pointer will be called and `node` will be safely deallocated.

Comment: Nice point. Thanks. Small correction though, that I _verticesList is a std::list, however your point applies to that as well in case default allocator is used.

Comment: @singhalmanik Right. I am so used to "vector everywhere" that I didn't even check twice. I will fix that, thanks :)